# Forward DNS request to mDNS resolution

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, mdns

I use mDNS (with avahi, and libnss-mdns) a lot in my home network. However, I've tried to setup Prometheus, and it simply does not care about system resolution, it just takes the name servers from `/etc/resolv.conf` and does a DNS resolution request to port 53...

Now I was thinking about running a DNS server locally and forwarding the DNS requests to the local mDNS resolution.

In a way, I envisioned something like this

> 1. Prometheus reads the `/etc/resolv.conf` and one of the nameserver entries is 127.0.0.1
> 2. As a part of the lookup it requests `localhost` to resolve `somenode.local`
> 3. After getting the DNS resolve request some service resolves it with mDNS (e.g: `avahi-resolve --name somenode.local` and returns the resolved IP
> 4. Prometheus receives the IP and works as usual

Are there any tools that can do this already? I'm aware there is `dnsmasq`, but so far I was not able to find if it can to such things.

Comment: maybe https://superuser.com/a/1614564/992527

Answer (score 0):

If you use `systemd` then it's already available. Here `/etc/resolv.conf` would point to [`systemd-resolved`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd-resolved.8) and that then uses mDNS and DNS to resolve the request.